# Finding tuple with first element equal to the second plus one

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

Given a list of tuples:

```
total = [(4, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)]
```

I want to check if the first number == second number + 1 in each tuple.
In case they are equal I need to return `False` and else return `True`.

I tried two different methods but both check only the first tuple (`(4, 0)`)  and then return `True`, despite that it should return `False` (because the second tuple `(2, 1)` is `2 == 1 + 1`).

**Attempt #1:**

```
for tuples in total:
    if tuples[0]==(int(tuples[1])+1):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
for a,b in total:
    if a==b+1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should switch to version 3.6+ while you are still learning - https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: If you are learning Python now, I strongly recommend you learn Python 3 instead of Python 2. Python 2 is now a legacy language, with support ending in just over 2 years.

Answer (score 3):

You are only testing the **first** tuple in your list. `return` ends the function.

Test **all** tuples before you decide to return `True`i:

```
for a, b in total:
    if a == b + 1:
        return False
return True
```

So when the first tuple is tested, the `a == b + 1` test is still false, so you continue to test the next tuple. At that point `(2, 1)` is tested and `False` is returned. If you were to remove the `(2, 1)` tuple from the input, then the `for` loop ends and the `return True` line is reached.

You can use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), together with the inverse test (not equal) to make the above loop more compact:

```
return all(a != b + 1 for a, b in total)
```

This returns `False` the moment a tuple that matches your criteria is found, `True` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def tuple_listing(s):
  return not any(c == b+1 for c, b in s)


total=[(4, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)]
print(tuple_listing(total))
```

Output:

```
False
```